# copy the scrolling parameters of ViewPager into another ViewPager for simultaneous scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a vertical ViewPager implementation which contains 3 fragments. In the middle and bottom fragment, I have added another normal ViewPagers. So far everything works i.e. swipe left/right triggers horizontal ViewPager page change and swiping up/down triggers Vertical ViewPager page changes. Now I need to make a change such that swiping left/right on the middle ViewPager should also trigger swipe left/right on the bottom ViewPager and vice-verse.

I need to pass the parameters of the Scroll function here so that transition occurs according to the user interaction with the touch screed. I have seen that "viewPager3.setCurrentItem(position)" causes abrupt trigger of the Scroll in ViewPagers. I need the case where the user changes the page really slowly or goes back to the same page again.

Answer (score 1):

Try a solution like this:

```
mFirstViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        mSecondViewPager.scrollTo(mFirstViewPager.getScrollX(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mSecondViewPager.setCurrentItem(mFirstViewPager.getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
viewPager1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
        viewPager2.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. That seems a good idea since onTouchEvent(event) is triggered before any other events. But I have handled the page change in the OnPageChangeListener() of ViewPager. Supposing I handle the touch first, then how do I pass to the OnPageChangeListener() ? I hope I'm clear :D

Comment: Other events will be handled too if onTouch returns false

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your way but getting some other problem unrelated to above. I'll fix those errors and mark the problem as solved. :D

Comment: I have seen that above method doesn't work. I printed the values of onTouchEvent(event) in both of the listeners i.e. viewpager1 and viewpager2. But only the  first value is printed. Eg: if I scroll the last page, then only the events from that page will be displayed not the other one which we have explicitly called. Thanks !!